# Change Fore Color in RegularExpression validation error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I change the fore color of the error message programatically?

```
   RegularExpressionValidator errorExp = new RegularExpressionValidator();
   ErrorExp.ErrorMessage = "You entered invalid data"; (Force it to be blue?)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
errorExp.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: when i do this and try to type Color, that property does not exist, instead it brings up ConsoleColor

Comment: You probably lack the reference to `System.Drawing`

Answer (score 2):

There is a `ForeColor` property, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx), which just sets an inline style, but I would recommend setting a value for `CssClass` and specifying your desired color in a style sheet.